# How to build a Cassandra binary distribution?

Tags: cassandra

I know how to build Cassandra - ant -autoproxy does the job. But how do I build a binary Cassandra release like cassandra-3.12-bin.tar.gz?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ant artifacts`

This will build you bin.tar.gz and src.tar.gz in the build directory. You might need to use the `-autoproxy` depending on your network settings. Generally speaking, you can list all ant targets with a command like `ant -p build.xml`